# PHPMyAdmin not importing CSV files

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I exported a table that had one entry, truncated the table, then tried to import that data which I just exported and it's not working. It says "Import has been successfully finished, 0 queries executed."

I made sure to check that "fields terminated" by and "fields closed by" match that of my CSV file.

I tried searching and came across the [PHPMyAdmin wiki](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/import#CSV) regarding importing CSV files and auto_increment fields. I even tried changing the one auto_increment field in this exported data to a 0 and it still won't import.

My table is as follows

```
Guests

id  |  owner_id   |  first_name |  last_name  | street_address |  city  | state  | zip  | phone  | email
```

This is the data which I exported directly from the table, and then tried to import

```
1;"1";"Test";"Guest";"123 Road";"New York";"NY";"12345";"1234567890";"email@gmail.com"
```

I tried changing the ID field to 1 and 0 (with and without quotes). There are no entries in the table when I tried to import it.

Answer (score 0):

On the import page, after browsing to the CSV file, make sure that “Columns separated with” is set to a semicolon `;`.  Also, which phpMyAdmin version are you using?